# Error with print(): "Output argument "varargout" (and maybe others) not assigned"

Tags: matlab, printing

I have been trying to write a simple script in MATLAB that plots an image, asks to user if they want to print it to a file, and (if yes) does this. However, I have met a strange error with the `print()` function. Here is my code:

```
plot(X, Y, 'red');

choice = input('Do you want to print to file this 2D image ? [y/n] ', 'y');

if(choice=='Y' || choice=='y')
{
    print(hFig, '-dpng', strcat(filename, '.png'));
}
```

If running, it stops inside the `if` statement with the error:

> Error in ==> print at 161 err.message='';
>
> ??? Output argument "varargout" (and maybe others) not assigned during
> call to "C:\Programmi\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\print.m>print".
>
> Error in ==> istogramma at 30  print(hFig, '-dpng', strcat(filename, '.png'));

Why am I getting this error and how can I avoid this?

Comment: this is probably not it, but you are setting `hFig` somewhere, right?

Comment: @mathematical.coffee Yes, before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` code with `{` and `}` seems strange, in MATLAB `{` and `}` are used for cell arrays and cell array indexing, not for code structuring. Further, the second argument for `input` must be `'s'`, not `'y'` as you have.

Fixed code:

```
choice = input('Do you want to print to file this 2D image ? [y/n] ', 's');

if(choice=='Y' || choice=='y')
    print(hFig, '-dpng', strcat(filename, '.png'));
end
```

**Edit:** to keep asking until user responds with 'y', 'Y', 'n' or 'N':

```
choice = '';
while ~ismember(choice, {'y', 'Y', 'n', 'N'})
    choice = input('Do you want to print to file this 2D image ? [y/n] ', 's');
end

if(choice=='Y' || choice=='y')
    print(hFig, '-dpng', strcat(filename, '.png'));
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So confusing! Because print command dont have any output argument!!!

I dont know clearly, but I think first of all check the hFig assignment. you can use

```
hFig=figure;
plot(X, Y, 'red');
% ...
```

if you want to create a figure and draw anything you want in it.
as the error says your output argument is not assigned so check the "filename" or you can use

```
[filename '.png']
```

instead.

I hope this help you. right now I dont have MATLAB and I cant test it for you.

P.S. : See this : [Why do I get the error '??? Output argument ‹variable› (and maybe others) not assigned during call to ‹function›.' ?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-FA99V6/index.html?solution=1-FA99V6)