# How to repeat an input if the user didn't type in anything and edit the entered input in matlab?

Tags: matlab

For example I have

```
x = input('value = ?')
```

how can I repeat this command if the user just press enter without any input and I would like to know is there anyway I could edit my input like just pressing the 'backspace' after I have keyed in.

Like I got two input variable now'

```
x = input('??');
y = input('???');
```

can I edit my first input if I have insert the first input data for x when the input function y is prompted out.

sincerely thanks for anyone that willing to give some helps.

For the 1st case:

I would like to have a code something like this

```
x = input('value = ?');
while x == %%no input%%
    x = input('value = ?'); %prompt the input command again
end
```

and

```
while x==error %% I want x in numeric input only
    x = input('value = ?'); %prompt the input command again
end
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Can you please provide a small code snippet?

Comment: Did you see this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998953/how-to-repeat-an-entire-process-in-matlab  I think it covers what you are looking for.

Comment: I have edited my question and sorry for being not specified @johnish

Comment: @Shai so is there anyway..hmm...

Comment: See my answer to another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634678/error-with-print-output-argument-varargout-and-maybe-others-not-assigned/10635416#10635416

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case:

```
x = input('??'); % if the user just hits 'enter' x is an empty variable
while isempty( x )
   x = input('??');
end
```

For a more robust method

```
x = str2double( input('Your input here:', 's') );
while ~isnan( x )
    x = str2double( input('Your input here:', 's') );
end
```

the command `input('??', 's')` returns the input "as-is" and does not try to convert it to a number. The conversion is done via the command `str2double`. Now, if the input is **not** a number (double), then `str2double` returns `NaN`. This can be captured by `isnan`.

Hopes this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

to repeat for blanks,

```
x=''
while isempty(x)
  x=input('value=');
end
```

for non-numeric, you could use something like

```
x=''
while isempty(x)
  try
     x=input('value=')
  catch me
     fprintf('enter a number\n')
  end
end
```